# Xamarin Build failed. An exception was thrown while dispatching a method call in the UI thread

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

Today I upgraded to the latest Xamarin Studio build (Mac 5.9.1.3) and did an immediate build, which worked and successfully deployed to my IOS device.
I have made a simple change to a class (added a property) now a build gives:
"Build failed. An exception was thrown while dispatching a method call in the UI thread."
No other diagnostics.

What does this error mean?

To isolate the error I have undone all changes and rebuilt - I get the same "Build failed" message, so the error isn't related to the code I changed but most likely my environment.

I have an Indie licence and running MVVMCross.

Can anyone help?
Thanks
Rod

Comment: It's always helpful to clean the project and/or restarting the IDE, when dealing with these kind of problems. I know it sounds a bit dumb, but it helps surprinsingly often. ;)

Comment: Yes I've been caught before when simply cleaning fixed it, but this time I've tried playing with the git setup in xamarin (I've been using sourcetree), re-cloning my repo, and reinstalling xamarin.ios and xamarin.studio. But this is frustrating - I accepted a xamarin update and have no xamarin support (I have an Indie licence witout support options).

Comment: It seems that this error is caused by SVN even though I manage my code with SourceTree/GIT:
[MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.SubversionException: '/Users/rjh/Documents/Business/Audio Puppy/Development/AudioSelfie/rodhemphill/audioselfie.git/AudioImage.Touch/Views/LandingView.cs~' is not under version control]
Anyone know how to make Xamarin Studio either not use version control or use GIT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to your comment.

Disabling Version Control in Xamarin Studio:

```
Tools -> Options -> Version Control -> General -> "Disable Version Control globally"
```